# Python - concatenate a string to include a single backslash

Tags: python

In Python 2.6, I need to create a string by concatenating `INTRANET\` and a userid such as `jDoe` to obtain a string `INTRANET\jDoe`. This will string will be a part of a SQL query. I have tried this a number of ways but end up getting `INTRANET\\jDoe` and hence my query does not return any results.

I want to do this:

```
a = 'INTRANET\\'
b = 'jDoe'
c = a+b   ### want to get c as 'INTRANET\jDoe', not 'INTRANET\\jDoe'
```

Thanks

---

The problem seems a little different:

When I print c, I get 'INTRANET\jDoe'. But when I append c to a list (to be used in a sql query) as below:

```
list1 = []
list1.append(c)
print list1

>>>['INTRANET\\jDoe']
```

Why is this ?

Comment: "I have tried this a number of ways" - the ways you tested that seems to be secret. So the answer is secret as well...

Comment: When you say "end up getting", do you mean when you print it? and chuckle @glglgl

Comment: You might want to try `print c` and `print len(c)`.  `c` only has one backslash.

Comment: You've made no attempt to remove duplicate `\` characters

Comment: Working for me using python 2.6.6

Comment: Please show the code for the SQL call.

Answer (score 2):

The additional `\` is there due to python escaping.

```
>>> print 'INTERNET\\jDoe'
INTERNET\jDoe
```

It doesn't affect the SQL you are using. You should look at another direction.

Comment: Thank Yossi..but when I print the concatenated string to a file, I get the output 'INTRANET\\jDoe'..maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: Yossi, my problem was still not resolved..I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code,

```
s1 = "INTRANET"
s1 = s1 + "\\"
s1 = s1 + "jDoe"
print s1
```

This will give the correct output `INTERNET\jDoe`

If you simply try to view the content of the variable you will see an extra \, which is an escape sequence in python. In that case it will show,

```
'INTERNET\\jDoe'
```